# Complex list manipulation

Tags: list, prolog

**Background**

I am having the following code that will take out the first list element in an inner list.

Example:
getFirstElement([[1, data1], [[2, data2], [3, data3], [[4, data4], [5, data5]]] ], O)
O will be returned as [2].

```
getFirstElement([H | T], [X| Tn]) :-
  [[X, _] | _] = H.

getFirstElement([H | T], O) :-
  getFirstElement(H, O) ;
  getFirstElement(T, O).
```

**Question:**

How do I extend the functionality so that it will return a list of all occurenses rather than just the 1st?

Example of wanted output:

getFirstElement([[1, data1], [[2, data2], [3, data3], [[4, data4], [5, data5]]] ], O). O will be returned as [2, 4].

Comment: What do you mean by "first element in an inner list"? Why do you need such an elaborate nested list? You realize that `[1,2,3]` is actually `.(1, .(2, .(3, [])))`, right? The nested list you are showing is strangely similar to the nested term of the "flat" list.

Comment: @boris Your right, I tried to remove all unneccasary data in order to make the problem easier to understand, I now changed to ordinary structure. The thing is that I must keep track of where an innerlist occurs, and my approach is to store the first element when a nested list occurs, as in the example this occurs for [2, data2] and [4, data4]

Comment: Still don't understand what disqualifies `1` from your answer. Is it because it is not the first element of the first element of a list in a list in a list? BTW, this is a really complicated structure, are you absolutely certain you need it? What is the rationale behind it?

Comment: @boris it is because when the list is passed on for the first time H will be unified with [1, data1] rather than the whole list [[1, data1], [[2, data2], [3, data3], [[4, data4], [5, data5]]] ]. Thats why, so the reason why 1 disqualifies is because it its not the first "element" of an inner list, but it is the first element in a list. The complicated structure is needed, since I basically have no choice, this is the data structure I am dealing with.

Comment: "since I basically have no choice, this is the data structure I am dealing with" so did you come up with this or is someone else giving you this data structure? The point here is that you are not really _solving_ a problem, you are creating problems by creating problems. Solving a problem usually involves removing the reason for having a problem.

Comment: @Boris I answered the question now myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126251/discussion-between-etg87-and-boris).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that one of the reasons for confusion is that you are using lists to represent pairs. If you used `X-Y` to represent pairs (as is conventional in Prolog) it would be more clear what's going on. So your first example would be:

```
getFirstElement([1-data1, [2-data2, 3-data3, [4-data4, 5-data5]] ], O)
```

I assume from the name of the predicate that O should be bound to the first element of "inner" lists at any depth and return all solutions nondeterministically (i.e. on backtracking).

You can do this by extracting these "inner" lists and then returning their first elements.

```
get_first_element(Xs, E) :- 
    inner_list(Xs, Y),
    Y = [E|_].

inner_list([X|_], Inner) :-
    is_list(X),
    X = Inner.
inner_list([X|_], Inner) :- 
    inner_list(X, Inner).
inner_list([_|Xs], Inner) :-
    inner_list(Xs, Inner).
```

For example:

```
?- get_first_element([1-data1, [2-data2, 3-data3, [4-data4, 5-data5]]], E).
E = 2-data2 ;
E = 4-data4 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getE([Num, Data], O) :-
    not(is_list(Num)),
    not(is_list(Data)).

getE([H | T], [X | Tn]) :-
  [[X, _] | _] = H,
  getE(T, Tn),
  getE(H, Tn).

getE([H | T], O) :-
    getE(T, O),
    getE(H, O).

getE([], O).
```

Things I missed was:

- splitting up the head when it was an inner list (missing all inner list in the inner list)
- handling the case when reaching a list without any inner lists, there was no rule added to let Prolog keep on searching if that was reached.
- finally there was a base case needed.

The code has one problem though, it returns O = [2, 4, 5|_G12383], rather than O = [2, 4, 5] when following is ran in prolog.

trace, getE([[1, data1], [[2, data2], [3, data3], [[4, data4]], [[5, data5]] ] ], O).